# Evaluate $\int \cfrac{150u^3}{e^{\pi u}-1}du$

Tags: integration

When I was watching Vtuber content, I found [this guy](https://twitter.com/Gwelu_os_gar) has an integral formula in his header of twitter.

$$\int \cfrac{150u^3}{e^{\pi u}-1}du$$

It seemed there is no attempt to Evaluate this integral on the Internet, so I wanted to try it myself.

**My Attempt:**

Let $x = \pi u$ , so $\cfrac{dx}{du}= \pi$ and $du=\cfrac{dx}{\pi}$.

also, $u=\cfrac{x}{\pi}$.

Rewritten the integral by $x$ and $dx$, We can write:

$$\int \cfrac{150u^3}{e^{\pi u}-1}du = \int \cfrac{150(\cfrac{x}{\pi})^3}{e^{x}-1}\times \cfrac{dx}{\pi}= \int \cfrac{150\cfrac{x^3}{\pi^3}}{\pi\times(e^{x}-1)}dx=\int \cfrac{150x^3}{\pi^4(e^{x}-1)}dx$$
And I stucked here. I also thinking about partial integration, but I have no clue.

How can I Evaluate this from here?

Comment: I tried $e^{x}=t$ or $e^{x}-1=t$ but I couldn't replace $150\times x^{3}$

Comment: without the useless factor of 150:  $$\frac{12 \pi  u \left(\pi  u \text{Li}_2\left(e^{\pi  u}\right)-2 \text{Li}_3\left(e^{\pi
    u}\right)\right)+24 \text{Li}_4\left(e^{\pi  u}\right)+\pi ^3 u^3 \left(4 \log
   \left(1-e^{\pi  u}\right)-\pi  u\right)}{4 \pi ^4}$$. where $Li$ is the polyLog function.

Comment: As shown in the above comment, the integral is most likely a joke.

Comment: As is said, you should never take an integral and try it unless you're sure it is solveable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is no closed-form in elementary functions for this indefinite integral because of a good reason.

The [Rieman Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition) and [Gamma function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiqgNiq877yAhUFzjgGHcCHC0YQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGamma_function&usg=AOvVaw2z-0G2Mzdshjd-_C_9-BZl) are related to each other by this integral
$$\zeta(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x -1 } \, dx$$ where $\Re(s) > 1$

So we get $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^x -1} \, dx   = \zeta(4)\Gamma(4) = \frac {\pi^{15}}{15}$$

However, we can have a power series representation using
$$\frac{x^3}{e^x -1} = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{B_mx^{m+2}}{m!}$$ where $B_m$ are [Bernouli's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Definitions).